# Combining multiple columns into one column in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I need to merge multiple columns of a data frame into one single column as below in pyspark. I am new to pyspark.

Dataframe input and output

[image]

These columns were actually key value pairs(10,20,30) at the source and I tried to **explode** but I am getting 'Column' object is not callable. The existing logic **splits** the column as mentioned above in the input data frame and hence wanted to proceed with the same.

Comment: Can you show the python code you tried? That makes it easier to see where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to know where the issue is with what you already tried without seeing your code, but you could use PySpark's [coalesce](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce.html):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce, col

df.withColumn("NEW", coalesce(col("MARK1"), col("MARK2"), col("MARK3")))
```

And subsequently drop the MARK1, MARK2, and MARK3 columns and then rename NEW to MARK1.